How to handle nested template classes with member functions of a template class
I'm trying to get more familiar with templates, specifically nesting of template classes. A very simple example to show what I'm after:
Assume we have a class Container, which has a data member field, a member function to mutate the data and a member function to print its contents. Here an implementation of this:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class Container {
  public:
    Container() :data_(0) {}

    void SetData(T data);
    void Print();
  private:
    T data_;
}; // class Container

template<typename T>
void Container<T>::SetData(T data) {
    data_ = data;
}

template<typename T>
void Container<T>::Print() {
    std::cout << data_ << std::endl;
}

The Print function obviously wouldn't work for something like std::vector, that case would have to be handled differently. I can write template specializations for specific cases, like std::vector<int>:
template<>
void Container<std::vector<int>>::Print() {
    for (const int &i : data_) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

But this would require huge amounts of code and repetition to cover other cases like short, long, float, double, or further nesting like with std::complex. My questions would be:

For only 1 level of nesting (e.g. std::vector<int>), how would the syntax to template the type inside std::vector (or some other template class) look like?
What about for deeper levels of nesting (e.g. std::vector<std::complex<double>>)?

My first instinct was to try something like this to overload my print function:
template<typename T>
void Container<std::vector<T>>::Print() {
    for (const auto &d : data_) {
        std::cout << d << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

which doesn't work, and I think that makes sense to me because with, for example
Container<std::vector<int>> c;

I'd be creating an instance of Container with the template parameter std::vector<int>, and not int. The next thing I intuitively tried was declaring PrintVector as a template function inside my class
template<typename T>
class Container {
  public:
    Container() :data_(0) {}

    void SetData(T data);
    void Print();
    template<typename U> void PrintVector();
  private:
    T data_;
}; // class Container 

And then implementing it like so:
template<typename T>
template<typename U>
void Container<std::vector<U>>::PrintVector() {
    for (const U &element : data_) {
        std::cout << element << std::endl;
    }
}

which also doesn't work. I think the problem here is that something like Container<std::vector<U>> is not actually a specialization of Container and I assume I would have to specialize the whole class to do it this way. My last idea would be to check what T is within the Print() function, and then handle it separate if it's a std::vector, std::complex, etc.

Let your container class return iterators for begin and end (and call them that way). Side not adding print functionality to a container class is not good design. Here is some explanation about how to make an iterator : https://internalpointers.com/post/writing-custom-iterators-modern-cpp. With that you can just use an instance of your template class inside range based for loops.

That's very useful, thank you. I understand that this example I used is not something you'd really ever (want to) find in reality. It was just the simplest one I could think of to get my question across.

Why don’t your template use concepts so that you don’t have to handle the whole world.

@msom Well (over)simplified examples sometimes end up being more difficult to get right ;) And the begin/end idiom is such a basic building block of C++ that it always makes sense to look at it. When done right you can always your own datastructure with algorithms and such ;)  For your example also look at this question on SO What are some uses of template template parameters

As an aside, before writing your own Print function you might want to look at std::print and std::format. If you are lucky, your compiler might already provide support for displaying vector. (New features, not available everywhere.)

Related to how-to-print-a-n-dimensional-stl-container
